# I want to convert 1fd93d1cf1f13d0d to 00011111 11011001 00111101 00011100 11110001 11110001 00111101 00001101

Tags: python, binary, hex

I used the following function:

```
bin(int('1fd93d1cf1f13d0d', 16))
```

but I keep getting

```
0b1111111011001001111010001110011110001111100010011110100001101
```

as output.

When I use `.zfill(64)` it becomes

```
00b1111111011001001111010001110011110001111100010011110100001101
```

Can someone please tell me where i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
hex2= 0x1fd93d1cf1f13d0d
spec = '{fill}{align}{width}{type}'.format(fill='0', align='>', width=64, type='b')
bin_representation = format(hex2, spec)
print(bin_representation)
```

represent your string into hexformat.hope it solves. format further according to your desired output

Answer (score 1):

you may do something like below:

```
# remove 0b at the beginning
>>> bin_value = bin(int('1fd93d1cf1f13d0d',16))[2:]
>>> bin_value
'1111111011001001111010001110011110001111100010011110100001101'
>>> len(bin_value)
61
# add leading 0's to make string length multiple of 8
>>> bin_value = (8 - (len(bin_value) % 8)) * '0' + bin_value
>>> bin_value
'0001111111011001001111010001110011110001111100010011110100001101'
>>> len(bin_value)
64
>>> bytes = [bin_value[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(bin_value), 8)]
>>> bytes
['00011111', '11011001', '00111101', '00011100', '11110001', '11110001', '00111101', '00001101']
>>> ' '.join(bytes)
'00011111 11011001 00111101 00011100 11110001 11110001 00111101 00001101'
>>>
```