# Getting 8 digits from given long hexadecimal number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on visual studio on the python project, and I have this hexadecimal numbers;

```
 0110200a03
```

So, I need to get 8 bits binary number from this one, and I want to show this hexadecimal number look like that:

```
00000001 00010000 00100000 00001011 00000011
```

It will look step by step every number end show it, for example
0=0000
1=0001
hexadecimal number will be long but it looks just number by number, so

The program which I wrote like that:

```
def hex_to_words():

   print ("Enter 'x' for exit. ");
   hexdec = input("Enter any number in Hexadecimal form ");

   if hexdec == 'x':
      exit();
   else:
      dec = int(hexdec,16)
    print(hexdec + " in Binary = " + bin(dec)[2:]);

hex_to_words()
```

So the output binary looks like that:

```
100010000001000000000101000000011
```

However,It calculates all of the numbers at the same time also when I try only "01" it gives only "1" on output, but I want to get "00000001".

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just add 0x in front of it for representing a hexadecimal number

```
>>> a=0x0110200a03
>>> a
4565502467
>>> bin(a)
'0b100010000001000000000101000000011'
```

and as for your second question just use a formatting function

```
>>> a=0x1
>>> bin(a)
'0b1'
>>> a=0x1
>>> '{0:08b}'.format(a)
'00000001'
```

but this is just formatting the output to 8 places

**EDIT**
This converts the number into another number that has zeros filled infront of it and the slices that number into chunks of 8 and displays it

```
from __future__ import print_function   
import math
a=0x0110200a03
string=bin(a)[2:]
length=len(string)
resultingnumberlength=int(math.ceil((length)/float(8)))
resultnumber=string.zfill(resultingnumberlength*8)
for binarystring in range(0,len(resultnumber),8):
    print(resultnumber[binarystring:binarystring+8],end=" ")
print()
```

Output

```
00000001 00010000 00100000 00001010 00000011
```

Comment: First of all thank you Albin for your answer but I want to get 00000001 00010000 00100000 00001011 00000011 from the 0110200a03, the program I write should look like that 01 =  00000001, 10 = 00100000 .. like that

Comment: @Alkyonemis I did make some more changes to my answer . Please feel free to correct me

Comment: Awe You are awesome thank you so much Albin you safe my life :)

Comment: Albin I want to ask another question to you if it is possible you can anser, I want to take a hex from the user and I changed the code but after  I changed, it gives str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, why it shows this error, is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656487/i-want-to-convert-1fd93d1cf1f13d0d-to-00011111-11011001-00111101-00011100-111100/52657036#52657036.

Comment: Thank you so much @bipin_s you safe my life too. Awesome help for me. Thank you a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be by using [bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/bitarray.html). Modifying your code:

```
import bitstring as bs

def hex_to_words():
    print("Enter 'x' for exit. ")
    hexdec = input("Enter any number in Hexadecimal form ")

    if hexdec == 'x':
        exit()
    else:
        dec = int(hexdec,16)
        b=bin(dec)
        b=bs.BitArray(b)
        b=[ byte for byte in b.cut(8)]
        print([x.bin for x in b])
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answer Saket, but I got an error for "ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'bitstring'",)" do I need to add bitstring.py in directory module or?

Comment: Perhaps bitstring is not installed. Use pip to install, thereafter it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much you are awesome :)